# jqgrid bug with datepicker control

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jqGrid 4.5.1.  when I use the `datepicker` control, the format specified in `colmodel` is working only for edit.

when I select a date and add a row, it shows a random number as date in the grid (for example, it shows `2194-09-08` if I select `2013-08-28` from the `datepicker`).

Note the edit works, but only add a new rows has this problem.

The same does not happen when we use the old version of jqGrid(3.8.2).  I didn't try it, but I reference the old jqGrid libraries from this site
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFormEditing.htm

I think this is a bug in the latest version.  The files that I am including are:

```
jquery 1.9.1
jqueryUI 1.10.3
grid.locale-en.js
jquery.jqgrid.js
```

I think it is a bug that jqGrid does not work properly with the latest version of jQuery.

**Has anyone tried jqGrid with `datepicker` with latest jQuery, jqGrid and jQuery UI libraries?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a template:

```
var colDateTemplate = {
editable: true,
width: 200,
align: "center",
sortable: true,
sorttype: "date",
editrules: { date: true },
editoptions: {        
    size: 20,
    maxlengh: 10,
    dataInit: function(element) {
        $(element).datepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            buttonImage: '/images/calendar-icon.png',
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    }
},
searchoptions: {
    sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn'],
    dataInit: function(element) {
        $(element).datepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            buttonImage: '/images/calendar-icon.png',
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    }
}
```

}

And when I'm searching and select the field with a date, operators "is null" and "is not null" are missing.
I'm using jqGrid 4.5.2, jQuery UI Timepicker 0.3.1, jQuery UI - v1.8.20